# 413 - Request Entity Too Large

Tags: gmail-api

I can upload small drafts OK using the metadata endpoint (https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/drafts), e.g.:

```
{"message":{"raw":"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"}}
```

However, when I try a larger file that's still within the 35MB limit (e.g. an 11MB file), I get the following HTTP WebException:

```
The remote server returned an error: (413) Request Entity Too Large.
```

Is this a bug in the new API, or is this down to the fact I should be using the media endpoint instead for this kind of thing? If so, can anybody provide an example of how to do this using the .NET Client?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the /upload "media upload" path to upload anything over a few MB.  The URL and POST format are slightly different:

You'd do:

1. POST https://www.googleapis.com/upload/gmail/v1/users/userId/drafts
2. add a HTTP header like "Content-type: multipart/related; boundary=\"part_boundary\""
3. POST body looks more like:

```
--part_boundary
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

{
}

--part_boundary
Content-Type: message/rfc822

From: script@example.org
To: user@example.com
Subject: test

body here

--part_boundary--
```

See [this](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/drafts/create) for more info (which then links to [this](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/uploads)).

Comment: Thanks for the response (again!), GmailGuy! I've changed my code to use the multipart/related approach and it works now, albeit there's quite a delay in between finishing the HTTP request and the start of the HTTP response being delivered (e.g. 10 seconds). Hopefully that's just some early-days performance problems.