# Send large attachment with Gmail API

Tags: php, gmail-api

According to Gmail API to send an email with large attachments bigger then 5MB you need to use the instructions here:
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/uploads

The API is a not very clear about the details and I tried to use the explanation I found here:
[Gmail API PHP Client Library - How do you send large attachments using the PHP client library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29081343/gmail-api-php-client-library-how-do-you-send-large-attachments-using-the-php-c)

I get "**Entity too large**" error message every time.

Someone can succeded to send an attachment bigger than 5MB with Gmail API, and help me understand what I'm doing wrong?

My composer file:

```
{
    "require": {
        "google/apiclient": "^2.0",
        "pear/mail_mime": "^1.10"
    }
}
```

My code after reading everything is this:

```
<?php
set_time_limit(100);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
require_once 'client.php';

$googleClient = getClient();

$mailService = new Google_Service_Gmail($googleClient);
$message = new Google_Service_Gmail_Message;

$file = __DIR__ . '/pexels-photo.jpg';

$mime = new Mail_mime;
$mime->addTo('mymail@domain.com');
$mime->setTXTBody('');
$mime->setSubject('test');

$mailMessage = base64_encode($mime->getMessage());
$message->setRaw($mailMessage);

$request = $mailService->users_messages->send(
    'me',
    $message,
    array( 'uploadType' => 'resumable' )
);

$googleClient->setDefer(true);

$media = new Google_Http_MediaFileUpload(
    $googleClient,
    $request,
    'message/rfc822',
    $mailMessage,
    $resumable = true,
    $chunkSizeBytes = 1 * 1024 * 1024
);

$media->setFileSize(filesize($file));

$status = false;
$handle = fopen($file, 'rb');
while (! $status && ! feof($handle)) {
    $chunk = fread($handle, $chunkSizeBytes);
    $status = $media->nextChunk($chunk);
}

fclose($handle);

$googleClient->setDefer(false);
```

Comment: The docs says use [resumable upload](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/uploads#resumable) for larger files. Did you try that?

Comment: Did you read my code ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to send big attachments with gmail API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50805550/how-to-send-big-attachments-with-gmail-api)

Comment: @JakeSymons, Really? how can I be a duplicate of a question asked yesterday?

Comment: @YehudaHassine, were you able to figure out the issue? I am also facing the same problem. If I attach one file of 3.7MB payload size is 7.5MB and if I upload two such files it goes to 14MB and I am getting "Entity too large" error. If you were able to fix, please share.

Answer (score 0):

@MP In my case, the problem is that I needed to set the unencoded message size, not the actual file. like this:

```
$media->setFileSize(strlen($message));
```